# Is it possible to pass dynamically created attribute value from Lightning Component Helper to Lightning Tokens?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, scrolling, design-tokens

I would like to pass dynamically created attribute value from Lightning Component Helper to Lightning Tokens, and subsequently use the same in CSS.

I'm trying to avoid using JavaScript to set style dynamically as I recently faced an issue in setting the same(using JavaScript) in a Salesforce instance to enable scroll functionality using `ui:scrollerWrapper`(by setting it's parent div's height[Since `ui:scrollerWrapper` [would be out of scope]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151463/unable-to-add-custom-scroll-due-to-component-namespace-encapsulation-when-lock)).

It would be great if someone could provide any insights on this.